# Using confirmSetupIntent on stripe-react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm making a shift from `tipsi-stripe` to `stripe-react-native` and I'm having some trouble getting `confirmSetupIntent` to work.

I'm getting a `paymentIntentClientSecret` from our server, and I have a custom credit card form from which I used to collect the card details and send in to `confirmSetupIntent` on `tipsi-stripe`, but it seems like that this doesn't work on `stripe-react-native`.

I'm calling the function like so, with some placeholder test data:

```js
const result = await confirmSetupIntent(
          clientSecret,
          {
            type: 'Card',
          },
          {
            brand: 'Visa',
            last4: '4242',
            expiryYear: 22,
            expiryMonth: 4,
            postalCode: '90001',
          }
        )

console.log('Stripe confirmSetupIntent result', result)
```

And I get the following response:

[image]

I guess I'm not sure how Stripe expects the card details to be passed in. Has anyone else experienced the same issue? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It seems like we can only use the components provided by `Stripe` due to PCI DSS requirements. That's why this error occurs. Read more [here](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/stripe/stripe-react-native/345/862002851).